# Backspace does not work in neovim with that moving setup

Tags: vim, neovim

I have mapped C-h for moving left in insert mode, but when i try to delete previous letter with backspace, it not works. I was looking around and BS is the same that C-h, someone know how to remap BS to delete previous letters and make i still use C-h for moving?

I tried remapping but no success

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You said it yourself: `<BS>` and `<C-h>` are one and the same so you can't map one without mapping the other.